# Connecting Putty to a SSLSocket

Tags: java, putty

What I’m trying to do is write a small test program to listen on an SSLSocket and connect to it using PuTTY (in SSH), then try to print lines that I typed in PuTTY session on java side. Problem that I’m currently facing is with the handshake. Looks like the sslsocket.startHandshake() does not complete and it’s just waiting at that point (I’m getting a “javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake” exception msg when I kill PuTTY).

Following is the command I used to create my key store:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias test -keystore ks1.jks -storepass password1 -validity 360 -keysize 1024
```

Code:

```
...
char[] keyPassword =  "password1".toCharArray();
FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream("ks1.jks"); 

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(keyFile, keyPassword);

SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(7777);

SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
sslsocket.startHandshake();

InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

String string = null;
while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(">" + string);
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY does not know SSL.

It supports SSH, what is a completelly different protocol.

PuTTY also supports raw connection, but as SSL is a binary protocol, it is nearly impossible to "type" SSL packets on the console.